# Can I use SparkSQL "java_method" to call my own Java method?

Tags: apache-spark

SparkSQL has a way of calling a Java method using the [java_method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#java_method) function. The doc has an example like this:

```
SELECT java_method('java.util.UUID', 'randomUUID');
```

For my project I'd like to **create & call my own Java method** - however I don't know whether SparkSQL supports this or not. The doc doesn't mention anything about calling custom Java methods.

So, does anyone know how to accomplish this or has anyone already created & called his/her own Java method with SparkSQL? I'd be really interested to know!

Regards, Michael

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call and pass parameters as well.

You can use the UDF function too using UDF(function name)

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you have any examples and configuration hints? e.g. where to put my custom jar file? Regards, Michael